# Gap of the Gods

Tags: lateral-thinking, knowledge

Fill in the missing Gods, in the correct order:

1. Hermes
2. Aphrodite
3. ?
4. Ares
5. Zeus
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?

Credit to my daughter for the inspiration for this puzzle!

Comment: (Wasn't that last edit a miscorrection?)

Comment: Yes. **Ares** is correct. I've re-corrected.

Comment: Huh. I showed this puzzle to my wife and she was so confident that it was Aries I didn't even double check! I'll have to tell her the bad news ;-) Is it bad that I'm looking forward to it.

Comment: **ARIES** is the zodiac constellation of The Ram; **ARES** is the god.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is:

> 1. Hermes
> 2. Aphrodite
> 3. Gaia
> 4. Ares
> 5. Zeus
> 6. Cronus
> 7. Caelus
> 8. Poseidon

The connection/order is:

> the Greek/Roman equivalent names of the gods for whom the planets of the solar system are named. They’re all Roman->Greek except Uranus->Caelus.

Comment: I'm thinking #7 has the error, yes?

Comment: @phroureo - It depends on what the querent was looking for. A check of Wikipedia suggests that #7 should only have been a spelling change, rather than an "equivalence" as the remainder are.

Comment: It looks like there was quite a timing coincidence between my comment, the edit, and OP's (now deleted) comment. I think the answer is right now, though. :)

Comment: An absence of a 9th item on this list has greatly disappointed the god of the underworld...

Comment: @DqwertyC It's also lacking Demeter as well, alas.

Answer (score 3):

> 3 should be GAIA, 6 should be CHRONOS/CRONOS/KRONOS, 7 should be OURANOS, 8 should be POSEIDON. The actual names of the planets are all taken from the Romans, but *they* took URANUS directly from the Greek, simply Latinizing the spelling. The list provided is the Greek equivalent mythic figures to the names of the planets (1 - MERCURY, 2 - VENUS, 4 - MARS, 5 - JUPITER). If you hold that PLUTO should remain among the planets, this name, too, was a Latinization of Greek PLOUTON. The Roman equivalent was DIS PATER/DISPATER.

Comment: Interesting... Now I've read more about Pluto vs. Hades vs. Dispater than I ever expected to today, and learned a bit too! In case anyone was wondering, Hades eventually came to be called Pluto in Greek Mythology, and Hades was reserved specifically for Pluto's domain. (Curse you, Disney, for confusing me!)